# On Norms equalities regarding Frobenious norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A$ matrix ($m \times n ) $. Define Frobenious norm as:

$$ ||A||_F = \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m |a_{ij}|^2 } $$

Show that for given $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, we have

$$ ||x y^H ||_F = ||xy^H||_2 = ||x||_2 ||y||_2 $$

Attempt:

Let $x = (x_1,...,x_2)^T $ and $y = (y_1,...,y_n)^T$. We know $y^H = ( \overline{y_1},..., \overline{y_n}) $. Notice $xy^H$ is then an $n \times n$ matrix with general entry $x_i \overline{y_j} $. Hence,

$$ ||xy^H||_F^2 = \sum_i \sum_j |x_i \overline{y_j} |^2 = \sum_i \sum_j |x_i|^2| \overline{y_j} |^2 = \sum |x_i|^2 \sum |\overline{y_j}|^2 = ||x||_2^2 ||y^H||_2^2$$. Since $|z| = | \overline{z}| $ for any complex $z$, then taking square roots on both sides give us  $||xy^H ||_F = ||x||_2 ||y||_2 $.

Am I on the right track? I am sort of stuck of the other equality. will the same argument work?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\Vert xy^H \Vert_2 &= \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(xy^H (xy^H)^H)}\\
&= \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(xy^H yx^H)}\\
&= \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(x\Vert y\Vert_2^2 x^H)}\\
&= \sqrt{\Vert y\Vert_2^2\lambda_{\max}(x x^H)}\\
&= \sqrt{\Vert y\Vert_2^2\mathrm{tr}(x x^H)}\\
&= \sqrt{\Vert y\Vert_2^2\Vert x\Vert_2^2}\\
&= \Vert y\Vert_2\Vert x\Vert_2
\end{align}

$\lambda_{\max}(x x^H)=\mathrm{tr}(x x^H)$ follows from the fact that $\lambda_{\max}$ is the only positive eigenvalue of $xx^H$ (which has rank one), and from the fact that the trace of a matrix equals the sum of its eigenvalues.